# Nearest Integer function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $x \in  \mathbb{R}$, suppose $x>1$  and $a \in (0,1]$. Also, let $\lceil  \cdot \rfloor$ be the nearest integer function. 
How can I factor: $\lceil ax \rfloor=???$

Is $\lceil ax \rfloor=a \lceil x \rfloor$? One can probably find a counter example.

Is there a way to write this with a floor or ceiling operations?

Comment: $\lceil ax \rfloor$ is always an integer. Can you say the same thing about $a\lceil x \rfloor$?

Comment: No. You are right.

Comment: Is there a meaningful way of factoring it?

Comment: I'm not sure how this function is defined. What is $\lceil 0.5 \rfloor$?

Comment: lets say at 0.5 the function is 0?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, $\lceil ax \rfloor$ is always an integer, but $a\lceil x \rfloor$ is not (unless $a = 1$ in which case $\lceil ax \rfloor = a\lceil x \rfloor$ is trivially true). Hence, $\lceil ax \rfloor \neq a\lceil x \rfloor$ for all $x$. If you define $\lceil \cdot \rfloor$ such that $\lceil n+\tfrac{1}{2} \rfloor = n$, then we can write $\lceil x \rfloor = \lceil x - \tfrac{1}{2}\rceil$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\lceil ax \rfloor = \lceil ax - \tfrac{1}{2}\rceil$. However, I don't think there is a good way to factor out the $a$ without knowing more about $x$.